# Use powershell remotely using version of hyperviser

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm facing an issue actually, i have to run a powershell script on all my VM but this one has to be runned with the minimum of version 3.

Our VM are using the version 2 ans the HyperV the version 4.

I attempt to use the remote access from powershell using "Enter-PSSession" but when i try to run the script this one is using the VM's powershell.

Is it possible to force the script to run on the VM using the powershell version of the HyperV ? Upgrading the version on the VMs is not feasible for the moment.

Thank you

Comment: You cannot use a PowerShell version that isn't installed in the first place. Just because you connect from a host running PowerShell v4 doesn't mean that version magically becomes available on the remote host as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. PowerShell Remoting executes the code locally on the target computer.

If your code doesn't work and you can't upgrade WMF (PowerShell) on the target computers, then you would have to rewrite your code. Maybe you can use WMI, C#, legacy commandline utilities++ to achieve the same thing?